# Python Mock Class instance variable from another Class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I want to write unit test case for `foo_method`. What's the best way of writing unit test for this? How can I mock `Bar` object ?

code1.py

```
from code2 import Bar

class Foo:
    bar_instance = Bar(init1='nothing',init2='nothing')

    @classmethod
    def foo_method(cls):
        Foo.bar_instance.bar_method()
```

code2.py

```
class Bar:
   def __init__(self,init1,init2):
      self.init1 = init1
      self.init2 = init2
   def bar_method(self):
       # do something
       pass;
```

test_code1.py

```
def test_foo_method_shouldCallBarInstanceBarMethod():

#### how to write this unit test ####
```

Comment: Why not pass in the instance of `Bar` when initializing `Foo`?

Comment: Did you try anything from the [getting started](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html) part of the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) to mock the `bar_method` of `Bar` class.

E.g.

`code1.py`:

```py
from code2 import Bar


class Foo:
    bar_instance = Bar(init1='nothing', init2='nothing')

    @classmethod
    def foo_method(cls):
        Foo.bar_instance.bar_method()
```

`code2.py`:

```py
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, init1, init2):
        self.init1 = init1
        self.init2 = init2

    def bar_method(self):
        # do something
        pass
```

`test_code1.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from code1 import Foo
from code2 import Bar


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(Bar, 'bar_method', return_value='bar')
    def test_foo_method_shouldCallBarInstanceBarMethod(self, mock_bar_method):
        Foo.foo_method()
        mock_bar_method.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
(venv) ☁  python-codelab [master] ⚡  coverage run /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59278328/test_code1.py                                                             
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
(venv) ☁  python-codelab [master] ⚡  coverage report -m                                                                                             
Name                                       Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/59278328/code1.py            5      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/59278328/code2.py            6      1    83%   8
src/stackoverflow/59278328/test_code1.py      10      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         21      1    95%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59278328